# Different Simulation results

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I have two similar objects, however, one of them behaves normally during the simulation process, while the other one doesn't, I can not figure out what results in this difference.
[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to apply scale on both of them.  After doing so, the simulation behaves like you'd expect.  (Be aware too that these are set to "convex hull" which is going to affect their collision-- they are not convex shapes.)

Comment: @Nathan, hi, I tried to print both of their scale, and find that, they are the same:      

>>> for obj in C.selected_objects:

...     print(obj.name)

...     print(obj.scale)

...     

Abnormal_one

<Vector (0.3000, 0.3000, 0.3000)>

Normal_one

<Vector (0.3000, 0.3000, 0.3000)>

Comment: Oh I see, it seems that the operation of "transform_apply" is not applied to the abnormal one. Thank you for your help! However, could you please explain shortly the reason why the missing of this operation results in this kind of phenomenon?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I could say.  As a general rule, always apply scale on physics objects.  It appears to screw up their bounding boxes.  I'd call it a bug, but it's been around forever, and there may be a reason why things are designed that way.  Yes, both your objects have unapplied scale-- however, the precise way that they're bugging makes only one look bad.  It's not that the other is okay; it just happens to work out, even though it's bugged.

Comment: @Nathan Thank you for your patience!